# Button after click doesn't work

Tags: android

I have a strange problem. When I run app and click button (btn_eng or btn_pl) i see log in logcat ("Erase dialog" or "Erase dialog PL") but next time when i click it does't show up and button doesn't do their onClick action.
I tried to make buttons to change language. In my app I have a dialog with data form Resources (string array) and when I change language i want erase dialog and make new with adequate data.

```
    //public static Activity act; -> before onCreate(..)
    this.act = this;

    Button btn_eng = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEN);
    btn_eng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("XXX", "Erase dialog");
            act.removeDialog(1);
            Locale locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config =   act.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            config.locale = locale;
            act.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            act.setContentView(R.layout.main);

        }
    });

    Button btn_pl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPL);
    btn_pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("XXX", "Erase dialog PL");
            act.removeDialog(1);
            Locale locale = new Locale("pl");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config =   act.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
            config.locale = locale;
            act.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            act.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you are resetting the content view in your onClick. Calling `setContentView` does **not** cause `onCreate` to be run - and that is where (I'm guessing) you link the `onClick` listener to the button. It **does** however cause a whole new instance of your layout to be displayed. You need to find a new way to refresh your screen, not replace your screen, with your new data. The best way would be to grab the wrapping `ViewGroup` for you activity and call [View#invalidate();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)

Comment: You are right, instead `act.setContentView(R.layout.main);` i put           `act.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content).invalidate();` and it works :)

Comment: It help, but this solution works with strings.xml (after this operation they are updated in app) but this approach doesn't change buttons - i see buttons from drawable not from drawable-en which will be desirable solution

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView(R.layout.main);` calling more then one time is not allowed, If you want change your screen contents, You should have *Layouts/Views/ViewGroups* in your Layout/.xml file and update them instead of calling setContentView Again.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove setcontentView() call in each Onclicklistener and try to put below code and test

```
Button btn_eng = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEN);
btn_eng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("XXX", "Erase dialog");
        act.removeDialog(1);
        if(v.getId()==R.id.btnEN){
        Locale locale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config =   act.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = locale;
        act.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

   }
    }
 });

Button btn_pl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPL);
btn_pl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("XXX", "Erase dialog PL");
        act.removeDialog(1);
     if(v.getId()==R.id.btnPL){
        Locale locale = new Locale("pl");
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config =   act.getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        config.locale = locale;
        act.getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
   });
```

Please share the result and accept this if it works at your end as its working well at my end